# UI Component: How to filter a custom column with data generated by logic?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, filter, order-grid

I added a custom column named `Payment Code` to `order listing` page in admin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="payment_code" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PaymentCode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PaymentCodeOptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Payment Code</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

The data `Payment Code` isn't getting its value from database but calculated by logic as soon as the order listing page loaded. Now I want to filter orders by `Payment Code`.

My filter does show up and display all of the options in `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PaymentCodeOptions`, but when used, it returns error as it tried to filter by querying into db, while my fields is pure logic and no data is stored.

How do I do it?

Comment: You can create one fields into the databse table, and sve it value according to your logic and then you can show that fields here, so your filter is working as you want.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I'm considering that option, but by doing that, only newly created orders have the data, the old one won't have anything in it, right?